# One paragraph followed by enumerate within tcolorbox environment

Tags: spacing, enumerate, tcolorbox

[image]

If I type one paragraph followed by enumerate, there is no space between the item and the paragraph. If there is two paragraph followed by the enumerate, there is two paragraph. I want there is also space when I type only one paragraph. I used the [parbox=false] because I want the parskip inside the box the same as outside.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}


\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[parbox=false,width=\textwidth]
The paragraph. The paragraph. The paragraph. The paragraph. The paragraph. The paragraph. The paragraph. The paragraph.

\begin{enumerate}
\item
item item item item item item item item item
\item
item item item item item item item item item
\end{enumerate}
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}[parbox=false,width=\textwidth]
The paragraph. The paragraph. The paragraph. The paragraph. The paragraph. The paragraph. The paragraph. The paragraph.

The paragraph. The paragraph. The paragraph. The paragraph. The paragraph. The paragraph. The paragraph. The paragraph.

\begin{enumerate}
\item
item item item item item item item item item
\item
item item item item item item item item item
\end{enumerate}
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest to repeat the `\parskip` setting with a special style `parskipsetting` and not using `parbox=false`.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\tcbset{parskipsetting/.style={before upper={\parskip=1em}}}


\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[parskipsetting]
\the\parskip

The paragraph. The paragraph. The paragraph. The paragraph. The paragraph. The paragraph. The paragraph. The paragraph.

\begin{enumerate}
\item
item item item item item item item item item
\item
item item item item item item item item item
\end{enumerate}
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}[parskipsetting]
\the\parskip

The paragraph. The paragraph. The paragraph. The paragraph. The paragraph. The paragraph. The paragraph. The paragraph.

The paragraph. The paragraph. The paragraph. The paragraph. The paragraph. The paragraph. The paragraph. The paragraph.

\begin{enumerate}
\item
item item item item item item item item item
\item
item item item item item item item item item
\end{enumerate}
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]